# How do you reflect the laser in level 13?

Tags: ios, enigmo-2

On level 13 of *Enigmo 2* for the iPhone/iPad, you have all the tools to bounce the water, but no mirrors to reflect the laser beam that turns on. How do you solve this level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The booster drum (the strongest of the three drums) also reflects lasers.  You only get one of these on the level but if you position it high enough above the the laser you can reflect the laser down, off the walls and into the collector.